# how to convert utc time ti ist tim in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

my server is in other country . so i'm storing time in utc in c#. but i want to store in ist(indian standard time). how to save the time in ist? i want to store current datetime in ist timzone

```
gps.updatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

datatype of updatedDate is datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of possible timezones [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones).

For example, for the `(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna` you could to this way:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, timeZoneInfo);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this answer. u saved my lot of time.